# How to use Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost 3.3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, ninject

Who can tell me about Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost? I'm using this manual https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-a-OWIN-WebApi-application, but it looks like it's out of date, because UseNinjectWebApi method doesn't exists.

I'm trying to do this instead:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        WebServiceConfig.ConfigureRoutes(appBuilder);

        appBuilder.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private static StandardKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernel.Bind<IPropertyRepository>().To<PropertyRepository>().InSingletonScope();

        return kernel;
    }
```

But when I call my API controller method, I get a message that the default constructor doesn't exists.

```
public class PropertyController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IPropertyRepository _propertyRepository;

    public PropertyController(IPropertyRepository propertyRepository)
    {
        _propertyRepository = propertyRepository;
    }

    [Route("properties")]
    [HttpPost]
    [LoggerTrace]
    public IHttpActionResult AddProperty([FromBody] PropertyDto propertyDto)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely, your problem isn't in your controller, but in your `PropertyRepository` class. You have set your injections up for your PropertyController, but it probably can't resolve a constructor for your repository, since there is a dependency that isn't being bound there and it's looking for the default constructor and not finding it.

Comment: Thanks, but that's OK!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/Setting-up-a-OWIN-WebApi-application is actual. It was that I installed only Ninject.Web.Common package, and it was necessary to install additional Ninject.Web.WebApi package which contains UseNinjectWebApi method.